# Rewrite URL in ASP .NET Web Forms

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have just made a step back from ASP .NET MVC application and moved to ASP .NET Web Forms and I'm wondering is it possible to rewrite url in Web Forms as well. I have a following set of URLs to reqrite:

- Edit.aspx?type=grbat
- Edit.aspx?type=lrbat
- Edit.aspx?type=glsi
- Edit.aspx?type=llsi

As you can see, everything works on one page.

However, I would like to make URLs more user friendly and replace it with:

- EditGlobalTopic.aspx
- EditLocalTopic.aspx
- EditGlobalInitiative.aspx
- EditLocalInitiative.aspx

is it possible in ASP .NET Web Forms?

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at this before : **http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx** ??

Comment: More up-to-date link to Microsoft Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/iis-url-rewriting-and-aspnet-routing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an open source component: [URL Rewriter](http://urlrewriter.net/).

I've used this is in the past and was able to create friendly URL's quickly.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need url rewriting here (isapi or another similar tool) to achieve what you want.

Here you're accessing to 4 different pages, and they need to be created, or the server will respond with a 404

You could create these 4 pages and then redirect to edit.aspx with proper parameters, but still I think it's a better aproach to use url rewriting (as that's its purpose)

Answer (score 0):

**Hello You Can easily rewrite URL from Web.config using Bellow Method ,**

```
    <system.webServer> 
     <rewrite> 
       <rules> 
         <rule name="default">
           <match url="^EditGlobalTopic.aspx" />
             <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="\.axd" negate="true" />
               </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="Edit.aspx?type=grbat" />
            </rule>
       </rules>
   </rewrite>
 </system.webServer>
```

use

```
     <a href="EditGlobalTopic.aspx">Go</a>
```

It will redirect you on that page.